# Kubernetes seeding a mongo database

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

I've got a docker compose file that looks like the below and trying to get started with a Kubernetes setup that can create mongo deployments that seed a new database when it starts. I am using kompose convert to create the yml files from this docker-compose but its failing to find the mongo seed.

I don't think this is quite correct when it comes to Kubernetes and a proper way to seed a database although this is working fine for a docker compose up setup. Would a seed like this for kubernetes be better off in an initContainer setup? I'm not finding alot of seeding examples for Kubernetes and databases.

Any help here would be appreciated

the docker-compose i'm running the kompose convert on looks like the below:

```
version: '3'
services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo    
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db

  mongo_seed:
    image: mongo
    depends_on: 
      - mongodb    
    links:
      - mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-seed:/seed
    command:         
        /seed/database.sh &&
        /seed/users.sh

volumes:  
  mongodata:
    driver: local

networks:
  mongonetwork:
    external: true
```

the seeds .sh's are just lines like:

`mongoimport --host mongodb --db test --collection testwidgets --type json --file /seed/widgets.json --jsonArray`

The goal is to be able to spin these up in an environment. Would like to allow persistent scenarios and also just lifetime of the pods.

Comment: Are you expecting this mongodb to be similarly disposable like a `docker-compose` setup, or are you expecting the mongo to be a long-lived in-cluster service? IOW, how many times are you expecting this seed process needs to run?

Comment: I would like to support both scenarios. One for production environments, the other for easy spin up and tear downs in a more develop scenario. The seed process only running in the dev / test scenario but this could be happening a few times a week or so as new features are worked on - would like to associate a new set of linked services per that feature. For instance: dev is working on something for a jira card 1234. Would like to create a set of services associated with that.

Comment: And you mentioned `initContainers`; have you already tried that mechanism? In other words, is this a "survey" question, or you are encountering a very specific answerable problem while trying to implement a scheme?

Comment: I have been attempting the above but the data thats present in the docker-compose situation with the mount above, is not present in the kubernetes approach that was generated off the kompose convert method. So not knowing enough about the correct way to achieve the result that a docker-compose up does in Kubernetes, I need to examine some different options but I don't know enough on what those would be.

Comment: As an update, I have found out that some things in the docker-compose file just don't have a 1:1 conversion. Resource: http://kompose.io/conversion/